# Easy YAML emitting in Python

Tags: python, yaml

I have this numerical code which up until now has a bunch of `print`s in providing several pieces of information as the calculation runs.

To make it easier for me to process the information, I'm using YAML. For C++, the following syntax exists

```
YAML::Emitter out;
out << YAML::BeginSeq;
out << "eggs";
out << "bread";
out << "milk";
out << YAML::EndSeq;
```

which is nice enough to use. I wonder now if something similar exists for Python.
A rough equivalent I've come across just now is PyYAML, and the equivalent of the above would -- if I'm not mistaken -- look something like

```
print yaml.emit([yaml.StreamStartEvent(),
                 yaml.DocumentStartEvent(),
                 yaml.SequenceStartEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=True),
                 yaml.ScalarEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=(True, False), value=u'eggs'),
                 yaml.ScalarEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=(True, False), value=u'bread'),
                 yaml.ScalarEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=(True, False), value=u'milk'),
                 yaml.SequenceEndEvent()
               ])
```

Wow, that's verbose. Do you know of a less verbose syntax/Python YAML package?
There's always `yaml.dump()` of course, but it's important that the data gets written out instantly.

Comment: This is dangerously close to a 'recommend me some X' question, which SO is not the place for. I would recommend asking specifically for a less verbose Python YAML library (or a way to make PyYAML less verbose).

Comment: Yup, that's a good hint; reformulated.

Answer (score 0):

PyYAML tries to ensure that its output is always well-formed, so you can't emit a partial document.

The solution is to always emit complete documents!

```
import yaml
print yaml.dump(["eggs", "bread", "milk", "squick"], explicit_start=True)
print yaml.dump(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3), explicit_start=True)
```

This will output a stream containing 2 documents, that you can load with `yaml.load_all`.

Comment: What's a "partial document"? YAML doesn't have any closing tags as far as I can tell (apart from "]" and "}" for explicit lists and dicts maybe), and anyways this lengthy yaml.emit code above does produce something meaningful too. Well, dumping complete dicts and lists would be an option although nesting stuff wouldn't be possible here.